# Jenkins controller always takes >10 mins to connect to Windows agent using EC2 plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a Jenkins controller and build nodes set up in AWS EC2 instances. The Jenkins build nodes aka agent nodes always takes 30 mins to connect to master and it keeps waiting on winrm to come up. This 30min lag impacts our ability to process the build jobs in a timely manner.

> Waiting for password to be available. Sleeping 10s.
> WinRM service responded. Waiting 180000ms for WinRM service to stabilize on EC2

I have user data for the EC2 instances

```
winrm quickconfig
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="8192"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="18000000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="1200000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/client/Auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
```

It is puzzling that it always takes >10 mins. Any pointers on the areas/configurations i should look into?

Answer (score 1):

do not use winrm for jenkins agent - it is not stable.
builtin windows openssh server works ok

you can enable it by:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
Start-Service sshd
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
```

After that you need to connect agent via ssh with password or key

Comment: I will try. I am using ec2-plugin which is kind of forcing me to use WinRM. I havent found a way to force the plugin to use SSH for windows

Comment: In my case winrm ransdomly drops connections, even due job execution process. And dont catch agents after reboot. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-7jl4cxkzpggkq checkout here. It offer to use jenkins java agent service on widows.